# Expression causes mock repository to return null

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, nsubstitute

I'm trying to test a service method but in order to do that I have to mock my ReportRepository. Everything works fine except the call to the Include method makes the mock return null.

The following returns the expected report:

```
var report = new Report();
var reportRepoMock = Substitute.For<IReportRepository>();
reportRepoMock.Query()
    .ByReportType(ReportType.DELQ)
    .ToEntityAsync()
    .Returns(Task.FromResult(report));
```

But the service actually does the following:

```
var report = await reportRepo.Query()
    .ByReportType(ReportType.DELQ)
    .Include(m => m.Fields)
    .ToEntityAsync();
```

The problem is that when I include the 'Include' method in my mock, null is returned instead of the expected report so my test breaks with a `NullReferenceException`:

```
var reportRepoMock = Substitue.For<IReportRepository>();
reportRepoMock.Query()
    .ByReportType(ReportType.DELQ)
    .Include(m => m.Fields)
    .ToEntityAsync()
    .Returns(Task.FromResult(report));
```

So how can I include the 'Include' method in my mock?

I'm experimenting with fluent repositories so they're set up a little different. A lot of the following code happens in abstract, generic classes but I cut it out to keep the question length down.

```
public class ReportRepository : IReportRepository
{
    private readonly IDbSet _dbSet;

    public ReportRepository(IDbContext context) {
        _dbSet = context.Set<Report>();
    }

    void Add(Report report) { ... }
    void Remove(Report report) { ... }
    ...

    public IReportQueryBuilder Query() {
        return new ReportQueryBuilder(_dbSet.AsQueryable());
    }
}

public class ReportQueryBuilder : IReportQueryBuilder
{
    private IQueryable<Report> _query;

    public ReportQueryBuilder(IQueryable<Report> query) {
        _query = query;
    }

    public IReportQueryBuilder ByReportType(ReportType reportType) {
        _query = _query.Where(m => m.ReportType == reportType);

        return this;
    }

    public IReportQueryBuilder Include<T>(Expression<Func<Report, T>> property) {
        _query = _query.Include(property);

        return this;
    }

    public async Task<Report> ToEntityAsync() {
        return await _query.FirstOrDefaultAsync();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured this one out. Instead of setting up the mock as:

```
 reportRepoMock.Query()
    .ByReportType(ReportType.DELQ)
    .Include(m => m.Fields)
    .ToEntityAsync()
    .Returns(Task.FromResult(report));
```

I went with:

```
reportRepoMock.Query()
    .ByReportType(ReportType.DELQ)
    .Include(Arg.Any<Expression<Func<Report, Collection<ReportField>>>>())
    .ToEntityAsync()
    .Returns(Task.FromResult(report));
```